# Jquery/Ajax form POST submits empty to my API

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm having some issues using Jquery & Ajax to submit a form to my API that is powered by Flask-RestPlus & Python. When I run my API from CURL, or using swagger it works as predicted, however when I try to use Jquery/Ajax to submit a form to the same endpoint I am not getting any data from the form submission.

Here is the the HTML/Jquery

```
<form name="login" id="login">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
<script>
$("#login").submit(function(e) {

    var url = "/auth/login_user"; //

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#login").serializeArray(), // I've tried serializeArray() & serialize()
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data);
           }
         });

    e.preventDefault(); 
});
</script>
```

When I inspect the code inside the browser it looks like it is sending the form data, but when I print it in my console from my python function I can tell I am getting a None type.

Any help would be much appreciated. I know I can user Jquery.val() to get the value of each form element but it doesn't seem like the correct way to solve this issue.

Comment: You should be using serialize() and code looks correct, how is the php reading it?

Comment: I'm using python for the processing side. When I look at what should be the form data inside the python console it is coming over as 'None'. I need it to come over as a JSON response.. so

{ email: string,
  password: string
}

Comment: well if you want JSON, than you do not want searlize() and searlizeArray()

Comment: What would I want for it to send over the form as json?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Comment: You could always construct the JSON object yourself, setting each key to Jquery.val(). You'd also need to declare the contentType. Set this to `'application/json'`.Then back in Flask, you can parse this with `request.json['email']` and `request.json['password']`

Comment: Yeah I'm trying that now but I'm getting a failed to decode json object. I imagine it's because I'm using Flask-RestPlus.. I'm not sure what could be going on tho, because the API endpoint works fine when sending raw json. But this form is not.

Comment: Ah, that could be it. sadly I'm not familiar with Flask-RestPlus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with this issue.. It seems to be the way Flask-RestPlus/Flask takes in the ajax POST. Not sure exactly what was going on but I did figure out the way around this by using this Jquery lib; https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON

and my code like so..

```
    <script>
$("#login").submit(function(e) {

    var url = "/auth/login_user";
    var form_data = $('#login').serializeJSON();

    console.log(form_data)

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           contentType: 'application/JSON',
           data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // 
           }
         });

    e.preventDefault(); 
});
</script>
```